# Regex to convert GIS WKT from 3D to 2D

Tags: regex, gis, wkt

Can someone show me regex to convert this format:

`'LINESTRING ZM ( 574084.51000000 4229857.57000000 0.00000000 0.00000000, 574095.03000000 4229848.23500000 0.00000000 0.00870000)'`

to this

`'LINESTRING ZM ( 574084.51000000 4229857.57000000, 574095.03000000 4229848.23500000)'`

Only the first two numbers should remain between each comma. There may be an arbitrary number of these 4 coordinate sets.

I tried the following (via oracle sql REGEXP_REPLACE function), but did not get the desired results (detailed above)

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE( 
  'LINESTRING ZM ( 574084.51000000 4229857.57000000 0.00000000 0.00000000, 574095.03000000 4229848.23500000 0.00000000 0.00870000)',
  '(LINESTRING ZM )((([:digit:]+\.[:digit:]+ ){2})([:digit:]+\.[:digit:]+ ){2}(([:digit:]+\.[:digit:]+ ){2})([:digit:]+\.[:digit:]+ ){2})',
  '\1(\2, \5)'
 ) regex_output from dual;
```

Comment: You asked this exact question a few weeks ago and that is my answer you are printing, so I'll just post that as an answer again. With the information you provided so far, this answer works

Comment: What exactly went wrong? You said "detailed above" but I don't see any description of an actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb0077/7

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(value, 
  '(( [0-9]+\.[0-9]{8}){2})( [0-9]+\.[0-9]{8}){2}',
  '\1'
)
```

The below section of this answer is faulty based on my initial finding of some documentation where `[:digit:]` was used, switching to `[0-9]` resolved this. All it took was somebody to solve my lazyness and hand me a functional testbed for this.

---

It seems that the first time you asked this question it ended up deleted.

Here is my answer again (with proper formatting and some tweaks while I'm taking the time to re-answer a question that you deleted and reposted):

```
(LINESTRING ZM )\((( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2})( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2},(( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2})( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2}\)
```

and replace with

```
\1(\2,\5)
```

EDIT: If there are an arbitrary number of theses points which need to be trimmed you could match with a pattern such as

```
( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2})( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2}
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

Comment: Will,

I did not delete the other question.  I was pulled away from the office for a few days and when I returned, the old question was deleted (by someone else).  I tried to undelete it, but it said my undelete request was one of 5 needed to get the question back in active status.

I saw a comment on the deleted post that my question was not specific enough.

So I wanted to repost the question, in a more direct way, and post what I tried from the last thread (which you suggested).

I will try your tweaked suggestion and let you know.

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE( 
  'LINESTRING ZM ( 574084.51000000 4229857.57000000 0.00000000 0.00000000, 574095.03000000 4229848.23500000 0.00000000 0.00870000)',
  '(LINESTRING ZM )\((( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2})( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2},(( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2})( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2}\)'
   ,  '\1(\2, \5)'
 ) regex_output from dual;
 


Gives this result:


LINESTRING ZM ( 574084.51000000 4229857.57000000 0.00000000 0.00000000, 574095.03000000 4229848.23500000 0.00000000 0.00870000)

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE( 
  'LINESTRING ZM ( 574084.51000000 4229857.57000000 0.00000000 0.00000000, 574095.03000000 4229848.23500000 0.00000000 0.00870000)',
  '(LINESTRING ZM )\((( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2})( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2},(( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2})( [:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{8}){2}\)'
   ,  '\1(\2, \5)'
 ) regex_output from dual;

Comment: the output:      
LINESTRING ZM ( 574084.51000000 4229857.57000000 0.00000000 0.00000000, 574095.03000000 4229848.23500000 0.00000000 0.00870000)

Comment: Here is a link which might help us, so far I cannot figure out the syntax however.   https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: Also, if you have a free oracle account, you can enter the sql via their online sample/test database.  https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/index.html#

Comment: Sorry for the mild flaming, thanks for the follow up, seems like the pattern still isn't matching. :/ I'll take another crack later

Comment: No problem.  I appreciate your assistance/efforts.

Comment: I should add, there could be any number of comma-separated 3D points, which should be converted to 2D points.  (so any x y z m, should become merely x y)

Comment: If it helps, this oracle DB online simulator page is readily accessible:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/11a66/12

Comment: I tested with this simple sql, and it shows the results at the bottom (under the sql window).      SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( '1 2 3 4', '(.).', '\1') FROM   dual

Comment: okay, not having a testing space was definitely hindering me, but i didn't feel like setting up a test space. of course there's a tool like sqlfiddle, thanks, hopefully I can get this one nailed down